# Finding Acceleration of Two Objects Touching

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

Alex is asked to move two boxes of books in contact with each other and resting on a rough floor. He decides to move them at the same time by pushing on box A with a horizontal pushing force FP = 8.7 N. Here A has a mass mA = 10.6 kg and B has a mass mB = 7.0 kg. The contact force between the two boxes is FC. The coefficient of kinetic friction between the boxes and the floor is 0.04. (Assume FP acts in the +x direction.)

1) What is the magnitude of the acceleration of the two boxes?

I keep getting 0.47 and I can't figure out why that isn't correct. I'm a math major, this is jibberish to me, so if you could leave step by step instructions on how to solve i'd be forever grateful. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acceleration = (sum of forces)/(total mass).

total mass = 17.6 kg

Push Force = 8.7 N

Frictional Force = -0.04(9.8 m/s^2)(17.6 kg)

therefore, acceleration = (8.7-0.04(9.8)(17.6))/(17.6)

Comment: You're a life saver, thanks man.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: One more thing, how would you find the force exerted on mB by mA and vice versa?

Comment: Use the same principle, except consider the blocks separately instead of as one system. So the forces on the second block, which are the force from the first block on it and the frictional force, have to be equal to its individual mass multiplied by the acceleration you already found.

Comment: I keep getting .36 for some reason for the first block, is that anywhere close to being correct?

Comment: I got 3.46 N for the force from the second block on the first block.

Comment: Youre equation should be:   Fpush - (frictional force just for 1st) - (force from 2nd on 1st) = (mass of 1st)*acceleration

Answer (score 1):

The *net* force on the two boxes in contact is the vector sum of the applied ("pushing") force $ \ F_P = 8.7 \ $ N and the kinetic friction force $ \ f_k \ $ which acts in the opposite direction.  The magnitude of that frictional force is 0.04 times the normal force of the force vertically upward on the boxes.  Since the boxes are taken to be on a horizontal floor, the normal force equals the weight of the boxes, $ \ (m_1 + m_2)g = 17.6 \cdot 9.81 \ $ N.  The kinetic frictional force is thus $ \ 0.04 \cdot 17.6 \cdot \ 9.81 = 6.9 \ $ N.

Since this is motion along one dimension, the vectors in opposition just produce a subtraction of their magnitudes, so the net force is $ \ 8.7 - 6.9  \approx 1.8 \ $ N.  This is positive, so the boxes accelerate together in the positive $ \ x-$ direction, at

$$ \ a = \frac{F_{net}}{m_1+m_2} \approx \frac{1.8 \text{N}}{17.6 \text{kg.}} \approx 0.102 \frac{\text{m.}}{\text{sec.} ^2} \ . $$

On the contact forces, the lead box, B, has $ \ F_C \ $ pushing it in the positive direction and kinetic friction acting on it in the negative direction.  The acceleration of the box is the common acceleration we just found.  So we have

$$  F_C \ -  \ 0.04  \cdot m_B \cdot g \ = \ m_B \cdot 0.102 \ \Rightarrow \ F_C \ \approx \ 2.74 + 0.71 \ \text{N} \ . $$

For the trailing box, A, the applied force $ \ F_P \ $ is in the positive direction and *both* the contact force and the frictional force act in the negative direction.  So we have

$$  F_P \ - \ F_C \ - \ 0.04 \cdot m_A \cdot g \ = \ 8.7 \ - \ F_C - 4.16 \ = \ m_A \cdot 0.102 \ \approx \ 1.08 \ \text{N} $$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \ F_C \ \approx \ 8.7 - 4.16 - 1.08 \ \text{N} . $$

As we expect from Newton's "second law", the contact force acting on each box is equal in magnitude.

Comment: One more thing, how would you find the force exerted on mB by mA and vice versa? I thought I could figure it out once I had the acceleration but im still lost.

Comment: Be careful to mark the forces acting on each box individually and keep track of the directions/signs of those forces in finding the net force on each box.  The _vector_ sum of forces on each box should sum to the mass of _that_ box times its acceleration (the same for both in this problem).